# How to combine groups of columns as a bar plot in pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have 3 tables

| Morning | Tennis Score | Baseball Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 10 | 2 |
| Emma | 5 | 6 |
| Theo | 5 | 8 |

| Noon | Tennis Score | Baseball Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 5 | 4 |
| Emma | 8 | 2 |
| Theo | 12 | 9 |

| Evening | Tennis Score | Baseball Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 3 | 3 |
| Emma | 6 | 7 |
| Theo | 8 | 3 |

I need to club different columns from the tables and get a graph like this.

```
dataf = pd.read_csv('score.txt', names=["Tennis","Baseball"])

dataf.plot(kind='bar')
```

I get a plot as:

[image: Seperate bars]

Here the values are in different x-axis index. How do i combine and get it together? I also have to combine the values from different tables and plot in the same plot. The final plot should look like this:
[image: Final plot]

How can i group columns together and plot it in the same graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given these DataFrames:

```
m_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Morning': ['Jack', 'Emma', 'Theo'],
    'Tennis Score': [10, 5, 5],
    'Baseball Score': [2, 6, 8]
})

n_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Noon': ['Jack', 'Emma', 'Theo'],
    'Tennis Score': [5, 8, 12],
    'Baseball Score': [4, 2, 9]
})

e_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Evening': ['Jack', 'Emma', 'Theo'],
    'Tennis Score': [3, 6, 8],
    'Baseball Score': [3, 7, 3]
})
```

They should be [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) together and each DataFrame should receive an indicator column. Additionally, the `Morning`, `Noon`, and `Evening` columns should be [`renamed`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) so that they align in a single column:

```
keys = ['Morning', 'Noon', 'Evening']
plot_df = pd.concat(
    [df_.assign(id=label)
         .rename(columns={label: 'Player'})
         .set_index('Player')
     for df_, label in zip([m_df, n_df, e_df], keys)]
).reset_index()
```

`plot_df`:

```
  Player  Tennis Score  Baseball Score       id
0   Jack            10               2  Morning
1   Emma             5               6  Morning
2   Theo             5               8  Morning
3   Jack             5               4     Noon
4   Emma             8               2     Noon
5   Theo            12               9     Noon
6   Jack             3               3  Evening
7   Emma             6               7  Evening
8   Theo             8               3  Evening
```

Then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) into wide-form from long, [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to get index in order `Morning`, `Noon`, and `Evening` instead of alphabetical order, [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) so that columns are grouped by player and not by score type:

```
plot_df = (
    plot_df.pivot(index='id', columns='Player')
        .reindex(keys)
        .swaplevel(0, 1, 1)
        .sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
        .rename_axis(columns=["Player", 'Score Type'])
)
```

`plot_df`:

```
Player               Emma                        Jack                        Theo             
Score Type Baseball Score Tennis Score Baseball Score Tennis Score Baseball Score Tennis Score
id                                                                                            
Morning                 6            5              2           10              8            5
Noon                    2            8              4            5              9           12
Evening                 7            6              3            3              3            8
```

---

This can be simply plotted:

imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Plotting Code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, ax=ax, xlabel='', ylabel='Score')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 1 (simple plot)]

---

Alternatively update the [`facecolor`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_color) and [`hatch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_hatch) of the patches:

imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

plotting code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, ax=ax, legend=False, xlabel='', ylabel='Score')

players = plot_df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
score_types = plot_df.columns.get_level_values(1).unique()
# Create hatches (should be same length as types of scores)
hatches = np.tile(np.repeat(['/', '.'], plot_df.shape[0]), len(players))
# Create Colors (should be same number of colours as number of players)
colours = np.repeat(['green', 'pink', 'purple'],
                    len(score_types) * plot_df.shape[0])
# Iterate over patches, colours, and hatches to set the facecolor and hatch
for patch, colour, hatch in zip(ax.patches, colours, hatches):
    patch.set_facecolor(colour)
    patch.set_hatch(hatch)

# Add legend:
ax.legend(loc=1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 2 hatched and colors applied]

---

Or even further with custom legends:

imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
```

plotting code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, ax=ax, legend=False, xlabel='', ylabel='Score')

players = plot_df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
score_types = plot_df.columns.get_level_values(1).unique()
colours = ['green', 'pink', 'purple']
hatches = ['/', '.']
iter_colours = np.repeat(colours, len(score_types) * plot_df.shape[0])
iter_hatches = np.tile(np.repeat(hatches, plot_df.shape[0]), len(players))
for patch, colour, hatch in zip(ax.patches, iter_colours, iter_hatches):
    patch.set_facecolor(colour)
    patch.set_hatch(hatch)

# Add legends:
player_legend = ax.legend(
    [Line2D([0], [0], color=colour, lw=4) for colour in colours],
    players, title='Players', loc=1)

score_legend = ax.legend(
    [Patch(hatch=hatch, facecolor='white') for hatch in hatches],
    score_types, loc=2, title='Score Type', labelspacing=.65)

for patch in score_legend.get_patches():
    patch.set_height(14)
    patch.set_y(-3)

ax.add_artist(player_legend)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 3 custom legends]

---

Complete Working Example with 5 players from `import` to `plt.show()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

m_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Morning': ['Jack', 'Emma', 'Theo', 'Matt', 'Thomas'],
    'Tennis Score': [10, 5, 5, 7, 9],
    'Baseball Score': [2, 6, 8, 2, 4]
})

n_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Noon': ['Jack', 'Emma', 'Theo', 'Matt', 'Thomas'],
    'Tennis Score': [5, 8, 12, 3, 10],
    'Baseball Score': [4, 2, 9, 5, 6]
})

e_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Evening': ['Jack', 'Emma', 'Theo', 'Matt', 'Thomas'],
    'Tennis Score': [3, 6, 8, 4, 7],
    'Baseball Score': [3, 7, 3, 9, 5]
})
# concat
keys = ['Morning', 'Noon', 'Evening']
plot_df = pd.concat(
    [df_.assign(id=label)
         .rename(columns={label: 'Player'})
         .set_index('Player')
     for df_, label in zip([m_df, n_df, e_df], keys)]
).reset_index()
# pivot to wide
plot_df = (
    plot_df.pivot(index='id', columns='Player')
        .reindex(keys)
        .swaplevel(0, 1, 1)
        .sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
        .rename_axis(columns=["Player", 'Score Type'])
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, ax=ax, legend=False, xlabel='', ylabel='Score')

players = plot_df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
score_types = plot_df.columns.get_level_values(1).unique()
hatches = np.tile(np.repeat(['/', '.'], plot_df.shape[0]), len(players))
colours = np.repeat(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'pink'],
                    len(score_types) * plot_df.shape[0])

for patch, colour, hatch in zip(ax.patches, colours, hatches):
    patch.set_facecolor(colour)
    patch.set_hatch(hatch)

ax.legend(loc=1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 4 complete]

Comment: Does this work with a table with 5 rows(5 players). If i add a  color for each player(Grapht 2) `code` colours = np.repeat(['red', 'green', 'blue','orange','pink'], len(plot_df.columns)), only 3 colors are repeated for the plot.  How could i assign a color for a player with a table of 5 rows

Comment: I get an error at plot_df.columns.get_level_values(1).unique() \\IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2 .

Comment: Yes.  I have pivoted into wide format, like you suggested. Yet plot_df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique() returns,  Index(['Player', 'Tennis Score', 'Baseball Score', 'id'], dtype='object').  plot_df.columns.get_level_values(1).unique() returns an error stating Too many levels

Comment: is this possible. For every player plot a bar with no fill and hatches and the next bar filled with color. I have edited the question with a sample plot.

Comment: It's generally not good form on SO to add requirements to a question after the question has already been asked and answered. In the case where I messed up the math to have multiple players style correctly that is an acceptable case to clarify (and for me to edit the answer). But this new update should be a new and separate question about how to set hatches and colors in a specific way. If you'd like me to take a look at your new question just drop me a link like "Hey Henry I have a follow up question (link to new SO question) would you mind taking a look?"

Comment: Sorry about adding more questions to the existing one. I have posted a new question. If you could, please take a look. Thanks @Henry Ecker